# Divergence theorem in 1D

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, divergence-theorem

I have the following expression which I want to evaluate:

$$\int_{\Gamma}\nabla\cdot(\beta uv)d\text{l},$$

where $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a straight line segment, arbitrarily oriented in space. Denote its end-points by $E^-$ and $E^+$, the integral going from the latter to the former, and let $\mathbf{t}_{E^-}$ and $\mathbf{t}_{E^+}$ be co-normal vectors in the points $E^-$ and $E^+$ respectively, such that they are parallell with $\Gamma$ and point away from the line segment. $\beta : \Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a two-dimensional velocity field and $u, v:\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are scalar valued functions.

I want to compute this integral by using the divergence theorem. Is it correct to say that $\partial\Gamma = \{E^-\}\cup \{E^+\}$ and thus
$$\int_{\Gamma}\nabla\cdot(\beta uv)d\text{l} = \mathbf{t}_{E^-}\cdot \mathbf{\beta}uv|_{E^-} + \mathbf{t}_{E^+}\cdot \mathbf{\beta}uv|_{E^+}?$$

This feels intuitively correct having the fundamental theorem of calculus in mind, but I feel that it lacks rigor, since the line segment is arbitrary in space.

Edit: For clarification: the $\nabla$ operator on $\Gamma$ is defined using unique smooth extensions $\overline{\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{w}\circ\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x}$ belongs to a neighborhood around $\Gamma$ which allows the closest point mapping $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} - \phi(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x})$ to be unique. Here, $\phi$ is a signed distance function such that $\Gamma = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2: \phi(\mathbf{x}) = 0\}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ is the corresponding unit normal defined by $\mathbf{n} = \frac{\nabla \phi}{\lVert\nabla \phi\rVert}$. The exact definition of $\nabla\cdot$ of a vector field $\mathbf{w}$ on $\Gamma$ is thus
$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{w} = \nabla \cdot \overline{\mathbf{w}}.$$

Comment: If domain of $\beta$ and $u$, $v$ is $\Gamma$ then what is $\nabla\cdot(\beta u v)$?

Comment: Well in practice, we consider a tubular neighborhood around $\Gamma$ such that the closest point mapping is unique. This mapping this allows to construct a global coordinate system around $\Gamma$. I'm only getting introduced to this, so maybe it needs more context?

Comment: Is your definition of $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{w}$ not equivalent to $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w}'(\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x})) (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x}))$?

Comment: I think it is
\begin{align*}
    \nabla\cdot\mathbf{w} &= \nabla\cdot \overline{\mathbf{w}}\\
    &=  \nabla\cdot \mathbf{w}(\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x})\\
    &= \text{tr}\left((\mathbf{w}'(\mathbf{p}))(\nabla \mathbf{p})\right),
\end{align*}
where $\nabla \mathbf{p}$ is the Jacobian of $\mathbf{p}$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{w}'(\mathbf{p})$ is the Jacobian of $\mathbf{w}$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{p}$. I don't see a way going forward from here, however?

Comment: Domain of $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x})$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I've meant $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p}$ is classic 2D-divergence of $\mathbf{p}$ (which is scalar value). Domain of $\mathbf{w}$ is $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}$, so I've meant $\mathbf{w}'$ is classic derivative.

Comment: Ah I see. But it needs to be a scalar in the end, so with $\mathbf{w}'$ you must mean $\mathbf{w}' = w_1'(\mathbf{p}) + w_2'(\mathbf{p})$ where $\mathbf{w} = (w_1, w_2)$? If so, it's consistent with the notation with the trace which I wrote.

Comment: I must write $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{w}'(p(\mathbf{x})) \cdot (\nabla p(\mathbf{x}))$ as $p$ is scalar value. So $\nabla p$ is gradient.

Comment: Yes you're right. Essentially, I guess we have $dl = dp$ but I still don't know how get rid of the integral and only have the evaluation in the end points.. Also, I'm not exactly sure that my integral expression is exactly right. I want to find out what it is.